# SSD disk not showing up in BIOS

Tags: ssd, bios

My system disk, a Corsair GT 120, suddenly stopped showing up in BIOS. It has been working without issues before. 
I've checked the cables, the SATA port on the motherboard, the power cable. Tried connecting the disk to a different computer, but it didnt show up in bios there either. Nothing made any difference.

Is there any other steps I can try to check the disk or try to get data from it before I go and buy a new one?

Comment: What happened when you connected the disk to another computer? Did it show up on that one?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No, same thing there: Did not see it in BIOS

Comment: If the drive doesn't show up on more than one machine, then it sounds like the drive is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Firmware problems have been reported. The most common is the drive doing an internal maintenance operation that takes too long, causing the drive to miss its chance to be identified by the BIOS. Try this:

1. Connect the drive to a known-working SATA port.
2. Boot the computer into the BIOS setup.
3. Wait about ten minutes for the drive to finish any maintenance it might be doing.
4. Warm boot the computer by hitting control-alt-delete or selecting to reboot in the BIOS.
5. If the computer boots up and detects the SSD, upgrade the firmware.