# M.2 SSD doesn't show up in BIOS, Windows Installer and Disk Management

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bios

I built my computer with ASRock X470 Master SLI Motherboard and an ADATA - XPG 512GB M.2-2280 Solid State Drive and it does not show up on BIOS at all. The SSD is in the M.2 port snugly and I can feel that its heating up however, it didn't show up anywhere.

Comment: Similar question....https://superuser.com/questions/541860/ssd-disk-not-showing-up-in-bios?rq=1

Comment: @Moab My computer is new and my SSD only connects to a M.2. port, not a SATA port, won't help me.

Comment: Its still a similar issue, port is irrelevant to solving it.

Comment: Even new devices could be broken. However, seeing how it’s more than a month later now, you’ve probably missed your chance to have it replaced easily.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on where in the bios you are looking. I have a Gigabyte X470 board and in the drive list I only see my CDROM, but in my boot order I can select either of my two M.2 drives. Keep in mind that some M.2 will show up as they are SATA drives but most are NVMe drives. If you are still unable to select your M.2 drive as a boot option then you need to look into updating the BIOS of the board as some M.2 drives are not recognized in the early firmware for the X470 boards.

It is also worth noting that on most of the X470 boards the second M.2 slot is shared with the adjacent PCIe slot and if something is in the PCIe slot the M.2 port is inactive. As well some BIOS wont see an M.2 drive in the second slot if noting is in the first slot. Some BIOS updates have fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some motherboards have only PCI-e or SATA M2 slots and the SSD may be the other way around (I had this issue on one older Asus motherboard with PCI-e only slot and Intel SSD which was SATA).

Comment: Slots and devices are keyed accordingly. It is physically impossible to install an incompatible device – unless using a lot of force.